# Winforms app as Scheduled task

Tags: winforms, scheduled-tasks

I've got a winforms app that I developed to do batch processing on tens of thousands of students, now we're trying to run it nightly as a scheduled task.

I personally find it useful to be able to login to the box and see how it's processing by looking at the GUI, though the standard way it to convert it into a commandline app.(which radically limits the amount of screen realestae I can use for loggin messages)

Can I run the app as a schedueld task, the IT Guy whos scheduling says it's not running because it's a winform app. Are there any tricks needed to get it to run well, or am I forced to rewrite it as a commandline app with it's 80 char width limit.

Basicaly I just echo the log file to the screen in realtime to make debugging issues easier. So the gui is output only.

Its' running as the currently loggedin user, but the issue is that it does not run if the user is not currently logged in on the box,so when we leave for the night it fails to run.

Thanks,

Eric-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure it is running as the currently logged in account. If it runs as 'system' I don't think it will show up correctly.

I have one of these myself... and despise it. It only exists because I haven't had a chance to rewrite it into a proper service. Don't forget there are more ways to log than just outputting to the console.  ;)

Comment: It's running as the currrent loggedin user,but it will not run if the user is not logged into the box. So when we go away at night, it fails to run. Anyway around this?

Comment: No, not that I'm aware of. Could you just set that computer up to simply stay logged in as a service account?  (lock it when you leave if console access is an issue) These problems are sort of telling you that this isn't actually the right way to do this.  :)  I think the fact it is a GUI app is why it won't run when you aren't logged in; there is no desktop to work with?

Comment: Nope I'm trying to covnert it to as a winform or a commandline based on a commandline parameter.