# C# Winform app GUI is not showing run as scheduled task using .BAT file

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a winform app for sending bulk emails. I have scheduled this app using a .BAT file. The app is running as per the schedule and sending emails, but it is not showing the GUI.

When I search I found this link [Winforms app as Scheduled task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5793771/winforms-app-as-scheduled-task), As per that I have confirmed that I am using the same user account for scheduling the task and login into the machine. When I double click on the .BAT file, the app is running by showing the GUI. Does anybody knows what is the issue. Here is the content in my .BAT file.

```
c:

cd\

cd ABC

sendMailApp.exe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your last line, you could try using

```
call start sendMailApp.exe
```

I think this might fix it, call will cause start to run a new process and open a new window for the process which *should* show the GUI.

Docs here:

http://ss64.com/nt/call.html

http://ss64.com/nt/start.html

Comment: Why would it fix the problem to add `call`? [What does this "magic" code do?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/04/17/9551818.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tested this adding 'start ' on last line but that doesn't work for me.

Comment: Try call start sendmailapp.exe